# Seemingly impossible way to restructure sidebar into content based on screensize

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a layout structure for large screens which includes content, and then a sidebar with different content. It looks like this:

**Large Screen Layout**

```
Content Line 1   ¦    Sidebar item 1
Content Line 2   ¦    Sidebar item 2
Content Line 3   ¦    Sidebar item 3
Content Line 4   ¦    Sidebar item 4
Content Line 5   ¦
```

The big issue is this layout looks terrible on mobile so I've got a design which looks much better on mobile like this.

**Small Screen Layout**

```
Content Line 1
Sidebar item 1 Sidebar item 2
Content Line 2
Sidebar item 3 Sidebar item 4       
Content Line 3       
Content Line 4       
Content Line 5
```

The trouble is, I don't want to change the HTML structure based on screen size I just want to use mediaquery to change the CSS. However, even with being able to change the CSS I can see a way to insert the sidebar content into the main content.

I really don't know if this is achieveable or not, especially in a way which is compatible with modern browsers. I started to code up the large screen layout here but the question is, **how do I use mediaquery (no JS) to insert the sidebar content inbetween the main list content if the screen size is small.**

```css
body {}

.header {
  color: #81D2A0;
}

.subnav input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  width: 200px
}

.side {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Logo
</div>
<div class="subnav">
  <input class="search">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <ul>
      <li>Side 1</li>
      <li>Side 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want the items and sides to position in your snippet demo on small screen size?

Comment: @Anonymous I want it to be positioned how I showed it on the **Small Screen Layout** where they are just left aligned, with two appearing under each content item. I guess I can group the sidebar items by two in the sidebar originally to help things.